# Tracking database usage using php and Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am designing a php mysql webapp. In that, a database usage log has to be maintained , which will record 
   1.User ip
   2.Timestamp
   3.operation performed(Add,edit or delete)
   4.Colmns changed
   5.rowid
   6.old value
   7.new value

Please suggest any example scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using your own database class, just add this logging to that class. Otherwise you will have to make a database class to do it and start using that class instead of using `mysql_query` directly.

Answer (score 0):

There are many DB profilers available. You can configure that and use them. You can use XDebug.

Another link : http://particletree.com/features/php-quick-profiler/